# Making Cache data displayed responsive while New Data is Loaded

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using CoreData to display cached data while new data is loaded and then updated onto a tableView

The cached data is loaded fine but the problem is as soon as API is called to load the new data , the tableView becomes unresponsive i.e user can't scroll on the table or click anything and when the new data has completely loaded , it updates the tableView and it becomes responsive again

What I want to achieve is the app displays the cache data right away and the api is called and data loaded in the background.The tableView shouldn't be unresponsive while the data is being loaded and when the data loading from API is complete User can click a refresh button or swipe up to update the data

```
 // DID LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("did load")
        getAvatar()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        updateTableContents()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

My function where I display cache Data and call the API

```
 func updateTableContents()
    {
        do {
            try self.fetchedhResultController.performFetch()
            print("COUNT FETCHED FIRST: \(self.fetchedhResultController.sections?[0].numberOfObjects)")
        } catch let error  {
            print("ERROR: \(error)")
        }

        print("function called")
        let retrievedToken: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "acessTokenKey")
        let headers = [
            "Authorization" : "Bearer "+retrievedToken!,
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json"
        ]


        let url = "someURL"
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get , headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any]
                let data = json["data"] as! [[String : Any]]
                self.clearData()
                self.saveInCoreDataWith(array: data)
                self.nextToken = json["nextPageToken"] as? String ?? "empty"
                print("Token = "+self.nextToken!)
                for dic in data{
                    self.news.append(News(dictionary: dic))
                    print(self.news.count)

                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }


            case .failure: break
            }
        }

    }
```

My tableView Code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if let count = fetchedhResultController.sections?.first?.numberOfObjects {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell") as! NewsCell

        if let fetchedNews = fetchedhResultController.object(at: indexPath) as? NewsObject {
            cell.test(object : fetchedNews)

            print(self.count)
            self.count+=1;
        }
```

and all the Core Data storing and fetching functionality

```
  // Creating an Object
    private func createNewsEntityFrom(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> NewsObject {
        let context = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
        let newsEntity = NewsObject(context: context)
        newsEntity.newsAuthor = dictionary["author"] as? String ?? "default"
        newsEntity.newsTitle = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? "default"
        let images = dictionary["image"] as? [String: Any]
        newsEntity.newsImageURL = images?["link"] as? String ?? "default"
        newsEntity.newsID = dictionary["_id"] as? String ?? "default"
        newsEntity.newsPublisher = dictionary["publisher"] as? String ?? "default"
        newsEntity.newsPublishorIconURL = dictionary["shortenedLogo"] as? String ?? "default"
        newsEntity.liked = dictionary["liked"] as? Bool ?? false
        newsEntity.bookmarked = dictionary["bookmarked"] as? Bool ?? false
        return newsEntity
    }

    // Saving Data in Core Data
    private func saveInCoreDataWith(array: [[String: Any]]) {
        for dict in array {
            _ = self.createNewsEntityFrom(dictionary: dict)
        }
        do {
            try CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    // Fetching Data from Core Data
    lazy var fetchedhResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NewsObject")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "newsID", ascending: true)]
        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
         frc.delegate = self
        return frc
    }()

    // Function used to Clear Data from Core Data
    private func clearData() {
        do {
            let context = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NewsObject")
            do {
                let objects  = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
                _ = objects.map{$0.map{context.delete($0)}}
                CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.saveContext()
            } catch let error {
                print("ERROR DELETING : \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I was following this tutorial to know how to implement CoreData if that helps https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/parsing-json-response-and-save-it-in-coredata-step-by-step-fb58fc6ce16f

EDIT :

Tried calling Alamofire completion handler in background thread

```
 func updateTableContents()
    {
        do {
            try self.fetchedhResultController.performFetch()
            print("COUNT FETCHED FIRST: \(self.fetchedhResultController.sections?[0].numberOfObjects)")
        } catch let error  {
            print("ERROR: \(error)")
        }

        print("function called")
        let retrievedToken: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "acessTokenKey")
        let headers = [
            "Authorization" : "Bearer "+retrievedToken!,
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json"
        ]


        let url = "https://api.tapin.news/v1/posts/home"
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get , headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    switch response.result {
                        case .success:
                            let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any]
                            let data = json["data"] as! [[String : Any]]
                            self.nextToken = json["nextPageToken"] as? String ?? "empty"
                            print("Token = "+self.nextToken!)
                            self.clearData()
                            self.saveInCoreDataWith(array: data)
                        case .failure: break
                   }
                }
            self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

EDIT 2 : So I was testing around a bit and I don't think its an issue of background Tasks , since I moved the fetching code from updateTableContents to viewDidLoad and removed the function from viewDidLoad. So background API calling and saving to coreData is not even being performed

Still the UI takes a couple seconds to become responsive during which time I see no images , and then as soon as images load it becomes responsive

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("did load")
        getAvatar()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        do {
            try self.fetchedhResultController.performFetch()
            print("COUNT FETCHED FIRST: \(self.fetchedhResultController.sections?[0].numberOfObjects)")
        } catch let error  {
            print("ERROR: \(error)")
        }

    }
```

```
    // Fetching Data from Core Data
    lazy var fetchedhResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NewsObject")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "newsID", ascending: true)]
        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
         frc.delegate = self
        return frc
    }()
```

EDIT 3 : Here is my CoreDataStack

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = CoreDataStack()
    private override init() {}

    lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }()

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyAppName")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {


                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()



    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }


    func applicationDocumentsDirectory() {
        if let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {
            print(url.absoluteString)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Alamofire's completion handler, you assume it is being run in background thread, and then you call the main thread and update the tableView.
The reality is: **Alamofire's completions handlers already run in the main thread.**

This is causing your UI blockings, because you have expensive methods there, like these ones:
`self.clearData()`

`self.saveInCoreDataWith(array: data)`

Also this one might be expensive:

```
for dic in data {
   self.news.append(News(dictionary: dic))
   print(self.news.count)
}
```

Try wrapping your Alamofire completion handler in a background thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   <#code#>
}
```

Comment: I removed the for loop and wrapped the code in background thread like you suggested. Still not responsive initially when loaded. I edited the question to show what I changed

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Alamofire completion handlers are run on the queue that is passed, which is the main queue by default. You can easily pass whatever queue desired and then call out to the main queue for the UI updates, which is what I'd recommend instead of bouncing from the main queue to a background queue and back to main.

Comment: So shouldn't  wrapping it in the Dispatch Queue code like I did in Edit 1 make the UI responsive ? Also pls check my Edit 2 , even when I'm not calling the API and saving to CoreData , the UI takes a couple seconds to become responsive. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does this line of code do: ```try self.fetchedhResultController.performFetch()``` ?

Comment: I'm completely new to CoreData , like I mentioned in the question I've been following a tutorial (link given in question) but I imagine it fetches the entity's data defined in the FetchController (see code) from CoreData. Correct me if I am wrong